# Water Difference

Tags: calculation-puzzle, decanting-problems

While solving a puzzle, I misinterpreted the whole thing and ended up creating a new harder puzzle. Here it is:

> You have 2 cups filled with water, cup A is 5oz and cup B is 3oz. How can you get one cup to be filled with the difference in water between the 2 cups?

Comment: Are you sure this is a "harder puzzle" than the original?

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way, if I've understood the question right, would seem to be

> to empty out cup B, then fill B from A. Now what's left in A is the difference between the two.

Comment: That works and is a different solution than I came up with.

Comment: @иσαнcяişтiпσ What was your solution?